# Shutdown/Restart a pc that has fedora36 via XRDP

Tags: fedora, shutdown, reboot, remote-desktop, xrdp

I am repurposing an old desktop and installed fedora 36 kde version. I installed XRDP and it is working well for me. The only problem I am having is that when I try to restart or shutdown that pc while rdp'd in I get a black screen but the pc keeps running (so no restart or shutdown). When I hooked that pc to a monitor I saw that it actually logged out my user. So, can anyone help me in regards to shutting down / restarting from the rdp session. FYI using windows to rdp into the fedora box.

Edit: For shutdown/reboot I have tried to do it via the menu bar at the bottom which was kicking me out.

Comment: Edit the question to show how you tried to shutdown.

Comment: Does `sudo poweroff` work? Or `sudo reboot`?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov your method worked. Thank you. If you put it down as an answer I can mark your response as the answer.

Comment: For what it’s worth, Fedora uses PolicyKit to determine which users can shut down/reboot, and it requires you to be a user logged on at the console. Remote sessions through RDP do not count.

Comment: @jsbillings Care to write a proper answer? ;-) I knew it but was too lazy to write ))